# beamer full vertical centering

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

I am working with no predefined theme.

It appears that with

```
\begin{frame}[c]
Hello world!
\end{frame}
```

the text is not fully vertically centered; it's a little bit too high.

I managed to solve this problem using the minipage environment:

```
\begin{frame}[c]
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
Hello world!
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `beamerbaseframe.sty`, we could find the definition of `c` option for frames:

```
\define@key{beamerframe}{c}[true]{% centered
  \beamer@frametopskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1.5fill\relax%
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=0pt plus .4\paperheight\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=0pt plus .6\paperheight\relax%
  \def\beamer@initfirstlineunskip{}%
}
```

To make text fully vertically centered, we only need to redefine it, making `\beamer@frametopskip` and `\beamer@framebottomskip` have the same `fill`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{c}[true]{% centered
  \beamer@frametopskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=0pt plus .4\paperheight\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=0pt plus .6\paperheight\relax%
  \def\beamer@initfirstlineunskip{}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c]
Hello world!
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```